# LDAP query in Active directory

Tags: windows, active-directory

I am writing a LDAP query in Active Directory.

I want to search a user in Active Directory in Specific OU.

I run LDAP Query `(&(&(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(ou=Hosted*)SAMAccountName=vvishwakarma))` but didn't work

Remember I want to search SAMaccount in specific OU not entire Directory

Comment: you really need more info - what does 'but didn't work' mean. are you authenticated against the AD server?

Comment: We're still waiting for more information on what results you get

Answer (score 1):

first off, You are using the wrong objectcategory & objectClass.  You can probably leave out the objectcategory & class all together unless there is a chance there is a group with the same samAccountname.

What does this give you?

```
(&(objectClass=user)(ou=Hosted*)(SAMAccountName=vvishwakarma))
```

Comment: The above LDAP query was not worked either.

Comment: I want to build a LDAP query in Active Directory to search sAMAccountName in specific OU. Anyone help me out ....

Comment: You still don't tell us what results you get.  "not worked" isn't much help.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will solve at least some of your problems.

The first thing you need to do is remove incorrect objectCategories and objectClasses.

Next you should set your searchDN to the root of OU you wish to search:

For example, if you wish to search through your:

```
domain.local
    |- OUNameLvl1
        |-OUNameLvl2

SearchDN=OU=OUNameLvl2,OU=OUNameLvl1,DC=domain,DC=local
```

Then you can try with:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=vvishwakarma))
```

**EDIT**: I just realized you said you're doing this in Active Directory.

If using Active Directory Users and Computers, you can define a custom query where you will do the same as described above - place your search root to OU you wish to search through and then use the same LDAP query.

Comment: how do I add SearchDN=OU=OUNameLvl2,OU=OUNameLvl1,DC=domain,DC=local and (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=vvishwakarma)) in one query

Comment: You cannot. The only attribute that contains this information as a value is distinguishedName and it is build like this:
distinguishedName=CN=CONTAINER_NAME,OU=OUNameLvl2,OU=OUNameLvl1,DC=domain,DC=local.
In your case the filter should look like this:
distinguishedName=*OU=OUNameLvl2,OU=OUNameLvl1,DC=domain,DC=local.
Unfortunately, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684431%28VS.85%29.aspx) this attribute does not accept wildcards.
More info can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184978/ldap-root-query-syntax-to-search-more-than-one-specific-ou).

Comment: I must correct myself on the answer above since after some research I discovered that depending on the organization of your AD you can try to filter on "memberOf" field which should be defined for every CN. This should lead you to some results:
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=vvishwakarma)(memberOf=CN=OUNameLvl2,OU=OUNameLvl1,DC=domain,DC=local)). Please let me know about the results.

Comment: Any luck using the info from answers to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a super old question but here's hoping it's still useful.

I got this working by setting my ldap query base to the OU in question. ( [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631009/224334) ).

While you would normally set your base to the DCs involved, I got it to work by setting by base to the `DN` of the `OU` I wanted. `OU=Ops,DC=Big,DC=Co`, for example.